# Why is my JavaScript code not working on my ASP.NET web forms page?

Tags: javascript, webforms

I am running into a problem with a form submit in my web forms page. I have a function in place that should after confirming by selecting OK, do a `document.forms.submit` and send the user to another page.

I am not getting any error for the JavaScript when attempting to debug in Chrome and I am not getting an exception at all when trying to step through the C# function. Can someone with more experience with JavaScript input submit forms assist on this or show me a better way with the given code?

```
protected virtual void WriteCancelDiv(string claim_id, string promotion_id)
{
    string innerHtml = "<form action=\"TestPath/claim_cancel.aspx\" method=post><input type='hidden' name='claim_id' value='" + claim_id + "'><input type='hidden' name='promotion_id' value='" + promotion_id + "'>";
    innerHtml += @"<script> 
                   debugger;
                   function Clicked(){
                       var b = confirm(""This cannot be undone.  Are you sure you want to cancel?"");
                       if (!b) {return;}
                       else {document.forms[0].submit();}
                   }
                   </script>
                   <input class=""btn btn-sm btn-primary"" type=""submit"" value=""Cancel Claim"" onClick=""Clicked();"">
                </form>";
    cancel_div.InnerHtml = innerHtml;
}
```

Comment: When this web forms method is executed, does your submit button show up? And if it does, does anything happen when you click it?

Comment: @JennyO'Reilly the button is already present and once I select onclick, that is when it executes the function.  As soon as I execute the function, then it doesn't do anything

Comment: @JennyO'Reilly what I need is to refactor this to go to the page I have in the variable innerHTML.

Comment: Yes, but are there two buttons? The HTML you are "injecting" into the div creates a new submit button. Is that button displayed and what happens when you click that button?

Comment: By the way: I think this can't work the way you intend at all. The reason is that everything on an ASP.NET web forms page is located inside a HTML form element. This means your DIV is also inside that form. Now you are trying to create another form within that form, which is not valid HTML.

Comment: You should create the button on the server side not using HTML injection into a div element, but by creating the button as an ASP.NET web control. You can then use the `OnClientClick` to define a JavaScript code block to execute, once the button is clicked on the client side. The JavaScript code can already be on the page as a function and then you only have to add `myFunction();` to this attribute.

Comment: @JennyO'Reilly the only visible button is the input Cancel Claim button, the other input in the code is hidden. The answer you provided below seems like the path to go with and I will try this.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Mixing client side logic into ASP.NET web forms can be quite an arduous thing to do. In your code you are injecting HTML (including a form element) into a div. The problem with this is that every ASP.NET web control (including your div) is already inside a huge wrapping form element that ensures the post back of these controls.

ASP.NET web forms renders to simple HTML on the client side and this is how it works. There is always one huge form element around everything that you see. Unfortunately adding a form element into another form element is not valid HTML. So your approach is not going to work.

I won't provide any code here, but give you a description on how I would go about solving this.

**So this is what you are trying to achieve, if I am not mistaken:**

When **button A** is clicked another **button B** shows up. Clicking that **button B** first a confirmation dialog asks the used wheter he/she really wants to perform that task. If so, the user is redirected to another page.

**I would do it like this:**

1. You add **button B** as another server side control with visibility hidden.
2. In the click event handler of **button A**, you set the visibility of **button B** to visible.
3. You can add the confirm dialog to the [onClientClick](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7ytf5t7k.aspx) attribute of **button B**.
4. In the click event handler of **button B**, you do a redirect to the desired page.

Comment: Ok, thank you.  I will try this and see the results.

Answer (score -1):

this line

```
<input class=""btn btn-sm btn-primary"" type=""submit"" value=""Cancel Claim"" onClick=""Clicked();"">
```

replace it with

```
<input class='btn btn-sm btn-primary' type='submit' value='Cancel Claim' onClick='Clicked();'>
```

Comment: how can I rewrite this function?  Currently, even after changing the syntax of the onclick event in the input tag, it still does somewhat of a postback to the same page

Comment: @JustinWilliams: That is because the button is within a div that is within a form that is always automatically created by ASP.NET. Every control you add to the page on the server side is located within one huge form element. When you click any button that form is posted and executes another ASP.NET page life cycle. There is no way to get around that. That's the limitation of ASP.NET web forms and that is the reason why it is not longer used by most developers. It is just too unflexible. If you can, you should rater switch to ASP.NET MVC.

Comment: This answer is useless. It makes no difference to use `""` (escaped double quotes) or `'` (single quotes) in the questioners example.

Comment: @JennyO'Reilly thank you for your feedback.  This was much needed information.  I am discussing with my team member this now.